# " bei einer Rechnung über 47,70 Euro"-should it be "über"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence:

> Du hast dem Kellner bei einer Rechnung **über** 47,70 Euro nur 30 Cent Trinkgeld gegeben.

My question concerns the use of "über" in the given context. Pursuant to DeepL, it means "for a bill **of** 47,70 Euros". In such a case, shouldn't it be "von" rather than "über"?

Comment: This question seems to boil down to "in English it is *of*, so why isn't it *von* in German?" Apart from that translations don't reliably work that way, a look at the [DWDS word profile](https://www.dwds.de/wp/Rechnung) under the section *hat Präpositionalgruppe* shows that *von* is trailing by far. I'm inclined to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is to think that "über" only means "above" or "more than". Yes, it *can* mean that, but it can also mean "about". e.g.

> Ein Buch über Grammatik

isn't a book *above* grammar, but one *about* it. And, regarding your mentioned problem:

> Laß' uns darüber reden.

Let us talk *about* it, not *above* it.

The same with the "Rechnung": a "Rechnung über X" is one *about X* and hence one showing the exact amount of X.

If you wanted to express that a bill is *higher than* some amount you would use:

> eine Rechnung über/von mehr als X

or

> eine Rechnung von über X

Answer (score 1):

Both prepositions are possible. My feeling is that "Rechnung von" describes what the bill is, and "Rechnung über" has a slightly different perspective "what the bill says". But those are subtleties.

Comment: ...and, in addition: if the bill would be *more than* some amount it would be: "bei einer Rechnung *von über* X" or "bei einer Rechnung *von mehr als* X"